# Should Xcode Storyboard support segues from a UITableView with 'dynamic prototype' cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode4.2

I can't get this working. If I drop the master UITableView to use Static cells I can get the segues working, such that when you click on a row in the master it automatically pushes the Child controller on. But with 'dynamic prototype' cells, I click on one of the cells and nothing happens...

Am I supposed to programmatically push the child controller within the `prepareForSegue` method or something? In which case I'm not sure what advantage a segue here would have over the old way of just using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you don't have to manually push the child controller. Did you connect a segue in your storyboard file from the dynamic cell to the child controller? Also did you give your dynamic cells an identifier? You can also check out this tutorial:

http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/xcode-4-storyboard/

Scroll down to "Beginning iOS storyboards" and have a look at part 1 and part 2. I found them most helpful.

Comment: oh - I had an identifer, but I didn't match it up between the Storyboard and the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Working now.  So does this mean in the cellForRowAtIndexPath using Storyboard you only have to use a "UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];"?  That is you don't need the "if (cell == nil) { then create one..." as well?

Comment: As far as I understand, that is correct. The storyboard now takes care of creating them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prepareForSugue:` instead, `[table indexPathForSelectedRow prepareForSugue` will be called before the next scene's `loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set the reuse identifier of Table View Cell.

Comment: This should be as comment not as an answer.