# iOS 5 XCODE 4.3.2 Can a dynamic prototyped tableview use groups?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, ios5

I'm using storyboard and have a `UITableView` with dynamically prototyped cells. Now I was trying to make it grouped however every tutorial I can find only does grouping on static cells. When I select static I do see the 'sections' but not with dynamic. Is there an easy way to make my dynamic cells grouped?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You mean like changing the table view style to grouped instead of plain?  Or do you mean like adding headers and footers to sections?

Comment: This SO question and answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911588/should-xcode-storyboard-support-segues-from-a-uitableview-with-dynamic-prototyp

Comment: Yes, want to change to grouped style instead of plain. I can select grouped, but there is no sections option in the atributes inspector because I have dynamic prototype selected (instead of static). What I hope to have is similar to a food menu, header "sandwiches" with dynamic cells under that, then header "soups" and dynamic cells under that. Currently everything works in plain with dynamic cells, just no sections or headers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Grouped` style on the table view.

In storyboard select the table view by clicking on the part of the image that says prototype or in the left hand menu. There is style drop down box where you need to select `Grouped`.

Assuming you have your view set up correctly, setting multiple sections and adding the cells to the correct selection you will start seeing the cells grouped as they are with static cells.

You set the header of the section in the delegate to your UITableView by overriding the method below (If you are using a UITableViewController you set it there)

```
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // set title of section here  
}
```

There is a similar method for the footer

[iOS 5 XCODE 4.3.2 Can a dynamic prototyped tableview use groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605756/ios-5-xcode-4-3-2-can-a-dynamic-prototyped-tableview-use-groups/10747378#10747378)

Comment: Thanks, i've been playing with and I think I got it now. but cant return nil right, have to do like this

`UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    sectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    sectionLabel.text = @"Lunch Menu";
    sectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return sectionLabel;
`

Comment: Yep, I was just being lazy with `return nil`, I have removed it now